# ValueError: Separator is not found, and chunk exceed the limit

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, subprocess, python-asyncio

I'm running an external downloader script through asyncio.subprocess and whenever I try to download large data `asyncio` gives the following error:

> asyncio.streams.LimitOverrunError: Separator is not found, and chunk
>   exceed the limit

What cause this, and how do I solve it?

```
import asyncio, subprocess, websockets, json
from os.path import expanduser, sep

async def handler(websocket, path):
    print("New client connected.")
    await websocket.send('CONNECTED')
    path = expanduser("~") + sep
    try:
        while True:
            inbound = await websocket.recv()
            if inbound is None:
                break
            while inbound != None:
                cmd = ('downloader_script', '-v', '-p', '-o', '/home/blah/blah', inbound)
                process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
                async for output in process.stdout:
                    for line in output.decode().split('\r'):
                        line = line.strip()
                        if line == '':
                            continue
                        data = {}
                        await asyncio.sleep(1)
                        if line.startswith('INFO:'):
                            data['INFO'] = line.split('INFO: ')[1]
                        elif line.startswith('['):
                            data['progress'] = line.split(']')[0][1:]
                        elif line.startswith('ERROR:'):
                            data['ERROR'] = line.split('ERROR: ')[1]
                        else:
                                data['message'] = line
                        print (data)
                        await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({'progress': 'DONE'}))
                await websocket.send('bye!')
                break
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print("Client disconnected.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = websockets.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', 8080)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(1)` is not needed when using `async for`.  I have updated my answer below with example of how to use `tr` to replace `\r` with `\n`.

Comment: To my understanding a replacement should work but it doesn't. I think I was maybe a bit unclear in my question, sorry. I have a progress bar in the output i have to parse. Strange thing is if the progress is relatively short (say 30 segments) it runs fine but if I try to download anything greater i get the output when the progress bar is at 100% or even `exit(0)` due to completion.

Comment: However, this is not the case with the regular `subprocess` module and the difference in performance between the two must be microscopic because _to me_ the use of a regular subprocess at least appears to be completely asynchronous in my output.

Comment: Your progress bar process might be buffering its output when not sent to a tty.

Answer (score 0):

Since `asyncio.subprocess` currently works best with newlines, maybe try running your script through something that replaces `\r` with `\n`.

Here is a small bash script that can help (`cr2lf.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
$@ | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Example:

```
# slow_ugly_writer.py
import sys
import time

n = int(sys.argv[1])

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("*" * i, end="\r")
```

Usage:

```
./cr2lf.sh python -u slow_ugly_writer.sh 10
```

And from within your program:

```
cmd = ('crlf.sh', 'downloader_script', '-v', '-p', '-o', '/home/blah/blah', inbound)
```